# Indexing a dataframe from a dataframe of row indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two python dataframes with equal shape, for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), index=np.arange(3), columns=['a','b'] )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=3, size=(3,2)), index=np.arange(3), columns=['a','b'] )

print df1
           a            b
0   0.336811    -2.132993
1  -1.492770     0.278024
2  -2.355762    -0.894376

print df2
           a            b
0          1            2
1          0            2
2          2            1
```

I would like to use the values in df2 as row indexes to select the values in df1 and create a new dataframe of equal shape.
Expected result:

```
print df3
           a            b
0  -1.492770    -0.894376
1   0.336811    -0.894376
2  -2.355762     0.278024
```

I have tried using .loc and it works well for a single column:

```
df3 = df1.loc[df2['a'], 'a']

print df3

0  -1.492770    
1   0.336811    
2  -2.355762
```

But I was not able to use .loc or .iloc on all columns at the same time.
I would like to avoid loops to optimize performance since I am working on a large dataframe.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy` selection

```
pd.DataFrame([df1[col].values[df2[col]] for col in df1.columns], index=['a','b']).T


    a           b
0   -1.492770   -0.894376
1    0.336811   -0.894376
2   -2.355762    0.278024
```

If you want to avoid `for` loops, you have to play with raveling and unraveling. In a nutshell, you flatten all your data frame in a single vector, sum `len(df1)` at each block to jump indexes to the beginning of the next column, and then reshape back to the original size. All operations in this context are vectorized, so should be fast.

For example,

```
df1.T.values.ravel()[df2.T.values.ravel() + np.repeat(np.arange(0, len(df1)+1, len(df1)), len(df1))].reshape(df1.T.shape).T
```

Gives

```
array([[-1.49277 , -0.894376],
       [ 0.336811, -0.894376],
       [-2.355762,  0.278024]])
```

Comment: very nice. i was thinking of some sort function here. but this serves. :)

Comment: Thank you! I am very curious to try and see how fast this is :)

Comment: Unfortunately the solution with ravel does not seem to work for sizes different from (3,2)...I am trying to find out how to fix it :)

Comment: ```df1.T.values.ravel()[df2.T.values.ravel() + np.repeat(np.arange(0, (df1.shape[0]*(df1.shape[1]-1))+1, len(df1)), len(df1))].reshape(df1.T.shape).T```   This seems to work for any shape.